# How to use StreamPlot to plot the unique solution in this directional field?

Tags: plotting

How can I plot the unique solution in this directional field using `StreamPlot`?

```
f[x_, y_] := x^2 - y^2
p1 = StreamPlot[{1, f[x, y]}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, Frame -> False, 
  Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y(x)"}, BaseStyle -> 12]
```

I want to plot the unique solution, for example, for y(-2)=1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand what you mean, you can use the `StreamPoints` option (e.g. `StreamPoints -> {{{{-2, 1}, Red}}}` ):

```
Clear[f]
f[x_, y_] := x^2 - y^2
StreamPlot[{1, f[x, y]}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
 Frame -> False, Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y(x)"}, BaseStyle -> 12,
 StreamPoints -> {{{{-2, 1}, Red}}},
 GridLines -> {{-2}, {1}}
]
```

[image: plot with specific stream line, in red, and gridlines]

Comment: You're the real one! Thanks!